# php or mysql gets stuck when importing in to db

Tags: php, mysql

we have a php script that runs this console command

```
cat import.sql | mysql -u user -ppassword
```

so it simply imports a file in to the DB

the file is quite big ~ 120 mb

but it contains only insert/replace queries
like this one:

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `actionList` DISABLE KEYS */;
REPLACE INTO `actionList` VALUES (1,'buttonClick','Click on a button'),(2,'buttonClose','Click on the close button');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `actionList` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

I removed the lock table from the code.

Now when this script is running my other pages cant load until this script is finished.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: try removing comments from top and bottom eg these ones `/*!40000 ALTER TABL`

Comment: What database engine?  Its probably locking the table for write so you can't use it until its done

Comment: yes but I removed the lock table from the sql code....

Comment: It doesnt matter if you removed the `lock` statement itself.  If a query runs that updates the table it will lock it... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't a DB lock it was the session lock.

As we ran the script it took a lot of time, and the session was open, so other pages try to use the session but couldn't.

So I added:

```
session_write_close();
```

and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use different password for import process and do not import as root user.

Also you can limit the user :

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'francis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'frank';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'francis'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
    ->          MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
    ->          MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
    ->          MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;
```

For more information :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html